# Sharing links behind a walled garden on Facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I have website that will both post to a user's Facebook wall, and allow him/her to share links through private Facebook messages.

The links that we would like to share can be behind a walled garden, meaning you'd have to be logged in to our site to see them. The problem is Facebook ends up sharing the redirect link instead of the original.

What is the correct way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate "fake" pages with the og meta tags, and with a meta refresh, url tag, or some script with document.location. This pages should not need log in, and must contain only the shared information.

Comment: thanks for the help and quick response. so whats happening here is that we are passing a code in the url that gives the recipient of the message access to the page. The reason their was a redirect and the reason why the message was stripped down to the redirected url was because the OpenGraph tags i had on the page did not have the code in it. apparently FB parses and looks for the OG tags before passing along the message. So, although I didn't have to resort to your method because it was a different problem, your method would technically work if I wasn't passing in the code already.